# Получить имя компьютера через IP адрес

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi

```
set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & ip & "\root\cimv2")

if Err.Number <> 0 then
    msgbox Err.Description
end if

set items = WMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
for each item in items
    msgbox item.Name
next
```

Запуск скрипта от имени пользователя получает имя хоста, а запуск от имени системы возвращает ошибку

> Разрешение отклонено 70

Каким ещё способом можно получить имя удалённого компьютера?

Comment: Может как-то через `nslookup`...

Comment: Даже если в сети развернута AD, то не факт что правильно настроена обратная зона. Поэтому при DNS-запросах адрес может не резолвится. Однако в стандартной конфигурации Windows сети включена поддержка протокола NetBIOS. И используя встроенную консольную утилиту **nbtstat**, можно попытаться узнать имя удаленного компьютера. Как вариант использовать **ping -a 192.168.1.1**. P.S. Кстати логично, что от пользователя **System** скрипт не работает - нет прав у этого пользователя для обращения к удаленному компьютеру по протоколу SMB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Active Directory добавил члена группы в **Администраторы домена**, но он имеет доступ к удалённому рабочему столу. Скрипт запускается от системы, подключение происходит от пользователя.

```
set locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator") 
set WMI = locator.ConnectServer(ip, "root\cimv2", "User", "Password")
```

Пока решил проблему таким способом, но буду рад любым другим вариантам.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку используется AD, то я предлагаю использовать источником для создания базы данных рабочих станций журнал аудита контроллера домена.
Вот пример сведений из записи (EventID=4624 / вход в систему), которая возникает при загрузке рабочей станции домена и её попытке связаться с контроллером доменом (на базе W2K8).

```
    Имя учетной записи:     COMPUTER0$
    Домен учетной записи:       DOMAIN-A
    Код входа:      0x316d2639
    GUID входа:     {47f539ad-1ea8-a704-b23f-c5f7d3bcf80d}

Сведения о процессе:
    Идентификатор процесса:     0x0
    Имя процесса:       -

Сведения о сети:
    Имя рабочей станции:    
    Сетевой адрес источника:    192.168.1.170
```

Как видно из текста, доступно **имя станции** (с добавленным символом **$** в конце). 
И самое необходимое - **IP-адрес** узла, который общался с контроллером домена.

Дальше дело техники:

1. Использовать техническую учетную запись с правами локального администратора контроллера домена, чтобы прочесть записи с журнала "Безопасность"
2. Распарсить XML-данные записей журнала.
3. Задать соответствие имени и IP, и занести это в базу.

P.S. Альтернативным решением было бы поднять службу WINS, которая работает в автоматическом режиме, практически не требуя настроек. Но, если мне не изменяет память, данный сервис имеет крупные уязвимости, вплоть до RTE.

Либо все же правильно настроить службу DNS. Так чтобы обратные имена корректно регистрировались в базе DNS.